# Access Categories and Keywords Hierarchy using OData

Tags: 2011, odata, taxonomy

How can I get the Categories and Keyword hierarchy using OData?

When I tried to retrieve Keywords using `[OData Service Object].Keywords`, I get all of the Keywords.  However, the parent is null and children count is 0, so I am unable to create the hierarchy.

Also, how can I get the Components and/or Pages that are associated to each Keyword using OData?

Comment: I suggest playing around with OData via the browser first to see what XML/JSON the web service returns.  Here is a link to get you started: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/content-delivery-web-service-odata-fundamentals

Comment: Also see [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_15124BEC1D284B9C9BDE05DA9AB10B7E) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) for the topic showing the item relationships and we can "`$expand`" on them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the below OData query to get the Parent and Child keyword hierarchy details.

`/odata.svc/Publications(362)/Keywords/?$expand=Children,Parent`

This is one web service call and once you have the results, use LINQ to query for a specific keyword.

The above using OData `expand` option to get Parent and Child node details.

e.g; 
`expand=Node1` --> expands Node1
`expand=Node1,Node2` --> expands Node1 and Node2.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Good thinking Ram.  I had totally forgot about $expand. I had edited my answer and +1 for you.

Comment: Consider also *accepting* the answer as an "official" thanks to Ram and also to show others what answered the question.

Answer (score 5):

If you look at http://myserver.com/odata.svc/Keywords you'll see a linear collection of Keyword entities.  Keywords that are nested within other Keywords (i.e. Children) will have a `<link href=".../Parent" />` property point to the parent keyword, while any Keywords that have nested Keyword (i.e. Parents) will have `HasChildren=true` and `<link href=".../Children />` point to a list of child Keyword entities.

The way that you can traverse the tree is by making separate web service calls to either get children or get parents via the `<link>` properties.  As Ram mentioned you can use `$expand` to get the relationships in one call.